# Sql Query Simplification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PunchClock]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StaffId] [int] NULL,
    [LocationId] [int] NULL,
    [PunchIn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PunchOut] [datetime] NULL,
    [PunchType] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [IsApproved] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsLate] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedPunchIn] [datetime] NULL,
    [ApprovedPunchOut] [datetime] NULL,
    [ManagerComments] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PunchInComments] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PunchOutComments] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ApprovedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ApprovedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PunchClock] 
    ADD DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsApproved]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PunchClock] 
    ADD DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsLate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PunchClock] 
    ADD DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Deleted]
GO
```

Query

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         StaffId,
         [Date],
         PunchIn, PunchOut,
         DayOfWeek,
         TotalHours,
         StaffTotalHour,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS [Rank],
         CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(TotalBreakHours) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) * 3600, 0), 108) AS time) AS TotalBreakHours,
         CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND, (DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(TotalBreakHours) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) * 3600, 0), 108) AS time), StaffTotalHour) / 3600.0) * 3600, 0), 108) AS time) AS StaffNetHour
      FROM 
          (SELECT 
               *,
               DATENAME(dw, PunchIn) AS [DayOfWeek],
               DATEDIFF(SECOND, PunchIn, PunchOut) / 3600.0 AS TotalHours,
               0 AS TotalBreakHours,
               CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND, (DATEDIFF(SECOND, PunchIn, PunchOut) / 3600.0) * 3600, 0), 108) AS time) AS StaffTotalHour
           FROM 
               (SELECT 
                    StaffID,
                    Date,
                    MIN(PunchIn) AS PunchIn,
                    MAX(PunchOut) AS PunchOut
                FROM 
                    (SELECT 
                         StaffID,
                         CONVERT(date, PunchIn) AS [Date],
                         CASE
                            WHEN PunchOut IS NULL THEN DATEADD(SECOND, 1, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(date, PunchIn)) AS date) AS datetime2))
                                 ELSE PunchIn
                         END AS PunchIn,
                         CASE 
                            WHEN PunchOut IS NULL THEN PunchIn 
                                 ELSE PunchOut 
                         END AS PunchOut,
                         PunchType
                     FROM
                         (SELECT 
                              StaffID,
                              PunchIn,
                              CASE
                                 WHEN CONVERT(date, PunchIn) < CONVERT(date, PunchOut) THEN DATEADD(SECOND, -1, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, PunchIn)) AS date) AS datetime2))
                                 ELSE PunchOut
                              END AS PunchOut,
                              PunchType
                          FROM 
                              PunchClock) tbl1
                     WHERE 
                         PunchType = 'P') tbl2
                GROUP BY 
                    Date, StaffID) dsag
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *,
                   DATENAME(dw, PunchIn) AS [DayOfWeek],
                   0 AS TotalHours,
                   DATEDIFF(SECOND, PunchIn, PunchOut) / 3600.0 AS TotalBreakHours,
                   '' AS StaffTotalHour
            FROM (SELECT StaffID,
                         Date,
                         MIN(PunchIn) AS PunchIn,
                         MAX(PunchOut) AS PunchOut
                  FROM (SELECT StaffID,
                               CONVERT(date, PunchIn) AS [Date],
                               CASE
                                    WHEN PunchOut IS NULL THEN DATEADD(SECOND, 1, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(date, PunchIn)) AS date) AS datetime2))
                                    ELSE PunchIn
                               END AS PunchIn,
                               CASE WHEN PunchOut IS NULL THEN PunchIn ELSE PunchOut END AS PunchOut,
                               PunchType
                        FROM (SELECT StaffID,
                                     PunchIn,
                                     CASE
                                          WHEN CONVERT(date, PunchIn) < CONVERT(date, PunchOut) THEN DATEADD(SECOND, -1, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, PunchIn)) AS date) AS datetime2))
                                          ELSE PunchOut
                                     END AS PunchOut,
                                     PunchType
                              FROM PunchClock) tbl1
                        WHERE PunchType = 'B') tbl2
                  GROUP BY Date,
                           StaffID) dsag ) tbl23 ) tblMain
WHERE Rank = 1;
```

RESULT

[image]
Query Simplification

The query has no errors or problems. It returns the results I want BUT the problem is that it has lot of subqueries and it doesn't meet SQL Standard ..

Can anyone simplify that or use another way to get same result or rewrite query in more standard and simple form?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Would some `JOIN`s not service what you are actually after here? I know you said you realise a subquery, in a subquery, in a sub query, in a sub query, in a sub query (yep, I said that 5 times) isn't good, but it seems like you're thinking programmatically, not set-based.

Comment: Can u write a query in standard form ..

Comment: Can I? Very likely, but I don't understand what your goal is here, and that's a lot of code to understand blindly. You'll probably be better off giving us sample data and expected results, and explain the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Larnu is there a link that has all the "bad habits to kick" gathered? These are interesting articles.

Comment: Yes, @GeorgeMenoutis [Bad Habits Revival](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-revival) ; You'll probably find quite a few us "regulars" on the `sql-server` tag link to these articles in the comments. [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) and [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) tend to show up a lot.

Comment: @Larnu So by using  scheme ,rewrite Query and Give Me Result like i shared in Result image ..

Comment: That's just an expected result, there's no sample data, and there's no logic definition. Images of data isn't really helpful to us either. Tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements are far better received. We have the DDL, so seems we just need some DML, the logic and readbable expected reults.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with transforming the nested subqueries to a "vertical" pipeline of Common Table Expressions (CTEs).

Something like:

```
with pc as
(
    SELECT 
        StaffID,
        PunchIn,
        CASE
            WHEN CONVERT(date, PunchIn) < CONVERT(date, PunchOut) THEN DATEADD(SECOND, -1, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, PunchIn)) AS date) AS datetime2))
            ELSE PunchOut END AS PunchOut,
        PunchType
    FROM PunchClock
), pc_p as
(
    SELECT 
        StaffID,
        CONVERT(date, PunchIn) AS [Date],
        CASE
        WHEN PunchOut IS NULL THEN DATEADD(SECOND, 1, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(date, PunchIn)) AS date) AS datetime2))
                ELSE PunchIn
        END AS PunchIn,
        CASE WHEN PunchOut IS NULL THEN PunchIn  ELSE PunchOut END AS PunchOut,
        PunchType
    FROM pc
    WHERE PunchType = 'P'
), dsag_p as
(
    SELECT 
        StaffID,
        Date,
        MIN(PunchIn) AS PunchIn,
        MAX(PunchOut) AS PunchOut
    FROM pc_p
    GROUP BY Date, StaffID
), pc_b AS
(
    SELECT StaffID,
        CONVERT(date, PunchIn) AS [Date],
        CASE
            WHEN PunchOut IS NULL THEN DATEADD(SECOND, 1, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(date, PunchIn)) AS date) AS datetime2))
            ELSE PunchIn
        END AS PunchIn,
        CASE WHEN PunchOut IS NULL THEN PunchIn ELSE PunchOut END AS PunchOut,
        PunchType
    FROM  pc
    WHERE PunchType = 'B'
), dsag_b
(
    SELECT StaffID,
        Date,
        MIN(PunchIn) AS PunchIn,
        MAX(PunchOut) AS PunchOut
    FROM pc_b
    GROUP BY Date, StaffID
), tbl123 as
(
    SELECT *,
        DATENAME(dw, PunchIn) AS [DayOfWeek],
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, PunchIn, PunchOut) / 3600.0 AS TotalHours,
        0 AS TotalBreakHours,
        CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND, (DATEDIFF(SECOND, PunchIn, PunchOut) / 3600.0) * 3600, 0), 108) AS time) AS StaffTotalHour
    FROM  dsag_p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *,
        DATENAME(dw, PunchIn) AS [DayOfWeek],
        0 AS TotalHours,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, PunchIn, PunchOut) / 3600.0 AS TotalBreakHours,
        '' AS StaffTotalHour
    FROM  dsag_b 
), tblMain as
(
SELECT 
        StaffId,
        [Date],
        PunchIn, PunchOut,
        DayOfWeek,
        TotalHours,
        StaffTotalHour,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS [Rank],
        CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(TotalBreakHours) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) * 3600, 0), 108) AS time) AS TotalBreakHours,
        CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND, (DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(TotalBreakHours) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) * 3600, 0), 108) AS time), StaffTotalHour) / 3600.0) * 3600, 0), 108) AS time) AS StaffNetHour
    FROM tbl23 
)
SELECT *
FROM  tblMain
WHERE Rank = 1;
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 48
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 69
Incorrect syntax near ','.